# AngularJS expression {{value + value}} doesn't work in IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, expression, microsoft-edge

I have got the following table with input fields:

```
<td class="col-sm-4" ng-bind="getOrderNameForHourRegistration(selectedProject)"></td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addMonday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addTuesday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addWednesday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addThursday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addFriday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addSaturday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input ng-model="addSunday" class="col-sm-1 form-control" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="" ng-maxlength="1" />
</td>
<td class="col-sm-1">
    <input class="col-sm-1 form-control" disabled type="number" value="{{addMonday + addTuesday + addWednesday + addThursday + addFriday + addSaturday + addSunday}}" />
</td>
```

This:

```
value="{{addMonday + addTuesday + addWednesday + addThursday + addFriday + addSaturday + addSunday}}" /></td>
```

Works perfect on chrome and firefox. But i cant get it to work on IE and Edge.
It just doesn't shows the value not even zero. No value at all...

Comment: try using `ng-value` without interpolation `ng-value="addMonday + addTuesday + addWednesday + addThursday + addFriday + addSaturday + addSunday"` which will evaluate expression and will place place evaluated value it in `value` attribute

Comment: Try also to use `( )` like this `{{ (addMonday + addTuesday) }}`

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks that solution worked :D! finally mabye i should have tried that one myself but ok.

Comment: @Michelem i allready tried that one before, did work for chrome and firefox but not IE